# Integrating managed web-content into existing J2EE app

Tags: java, content-management

I'm looking for a java based CMS application that will allow me embed specific UI 'component's or 'regions' (eg.  newsfeed,  page-section, video, etc.) into pages of an existing J2ee web application.  The idea is to mix managed content with custom web-application function, where the 'dominant' web-application is our custom application but it integrates these components for which the content can be manged by A CMS. I have looked through a number of CMSs (Jahia, Magnolia, Alfresco, Nuxeo, Walrus and a couple more), but haven't found anything that readily provides managed components that I can integrate easily. Integration can be at the controller, jsp or even client (Ajax/iframe) level, but I am trying to stay away from introducing portlets into my stack.

I am currently using Spring and Struts2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Portlet Framework](http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/jsr168/) suits your needs here. Many CMS's support this specification and the main point is to absolve you from doing the low level, often very messy integration you're talking about. I use Liferay 6 with moderate satisfaction.